# How to append to a newly created string list in Ocaml the elements of the other string list, extended with "1" and "0" each?

Tags: string, list, append, ocaml

I have a list like this: **["0","1"]** - and I want to create a new one looking this way: **["00", "01", "10", "11"]** - that is I want to create the extensions of the original strings, adding to them "0" or "1".

I've tried the following code, but it does not work:

```
let extendedPartialSolutions partialSolutions = let rec aux extendedSolutions originalList =
                                                        match originalList with
                                                        [] -> extendedSolutions
                                                        | x::tail -> 
                                                            aux x^"1"::x^"0"::extendedSolutions tail
                                                    in aux [] partialSolutions
```

The compiler issues the following error:

```
# let extendedPartialSolutions partialSolutions = let rec aux extendedSolutions originalList =
#                                                       match originalList with
#                                                       [] -> extendedSolutions
#                                                       | x::tail -> 
#                                                           aux x^"1"::x^"0"::extendedSolutions tail
#                                                   in aux [] partialSolutions;;
File "", line 5, characters 15-20:
Error: This expression has type 'a list -> 'a
       but an expression was expected of type string
```

How is it possible to fix it?

Comment: `aux x ^"1"` is parsed as `(aux x)^"1"`. `aux x` has type `'a list -> 'a` but `^` has type `string -> string -> string` resulting in the error you mentioned. You need some () in there. The rest looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution! It is:

```
let extendSolutions originalList =
List.flatten (List.map (fun x -> [x^"0";x^"1"]) originalList);;
```